# Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit complete system failure

Tags: windows-7, bios, boot, bsod, post

I'm having a problem with Windows. Here are my system specs:

- i5-2500K Sandy Bridge
- ASUS P8Z68-V PRO LGA 1155 Intel Z68
- G.SKILL Ripjaws X Series 8GB (2 x 4GB) 240-Pin DDR3 SDRAM DDR3 1600
- EVGA SuperClocked 01G-P3-1563-AR GeForce GTX 560 Ti (Fermi) 1GB
- CORSAIR Enthusiast Series TX750 V2 750W
- Seagate Barracuda Green ST1500DL003 1.5TB 5900 RPM
- ZALMAN CNPS 7500

At the moment the computer won't even POST. At first, in the middle of installing SP1, my computer restarted (as it should) but when it tried to boot, it got stuck at the Windows Starting screen. Thinking nothing of it, I restarted the computer and when it got back to the the Windows Starting screen, the computer very quickly flashed a BSOD and restarted. It eventually got into a loop where every time I started Windows normally, it would flash the BSOD briefly and restart after coming up with the Starting Windows logo. I tried to boot to safe mode, but there was no key to do it. Instead, it came up with the option to boot from the disk drive or the hard drive.

I tried the system recovery option and waited around 20 minutes. It looked like nothing was happening so I shut down the computer and restarted. I also tried to use the boot disk recovery which didn't work because my system considered itself a different operating system (because of the SP1 install) After trying all the other obvious options, we tried booting BartPE and that gave us a BSOD with error code:

> 0x0000007B (0xF78D6528, 0xC0000034, 0x00000000, 0x00000000)

I then thought that the problem might have been hardware so I reseated all the connections. Everything appeared to be seated correctly. Upon trying to boot again the computer would not POST.

If you have any thoughts on how to resolve this issue please let me know.

Comment: Definitely must be hardware related if it isn't POSTing.  What exactly happens during POST - how far does it get?  Do you get any beeps (do you have a speaker)?

Comment: With POST issues, the best starting point is to disconnect or remove everything except 1 stick of ram, the cpu and graphics, then add components one by one until it fails again

Comment: Tap F8 as you start up Windows, and select Disable automatic reboot on System Failure, and record the BSOD code. As well, try Startup Repair

Comment: @Luke No POST so I can't F8.

Comment: @Paul Tried your disconnect method for the sake of trying however I realize that it's probably hardware failure. I don't have a speaker so I can not listen to how many beeps it gives me. I did realize however that when turning my computer off, rather than simply clicking the power button (like I had been doing before) I had to hold down the button down. Because I have no POST (or possibly no graphics?) I can't tell if something is going on or not.

Comment: Ah, so nothing appears on screen at all?  If you have another graphics card / monitor around I would give them a go.  If you have to hold down the power button, then I reckon you are probably posting and loading the OS.  If the monitor doesn't come out of standby, it might be a faulty cable.  Perhaps you have a TV you could plug the PC into if you don't have another monitor?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out Windows had corrupted some data on my hard disk. Unfortunately I had to lose all of my data which is what I was trying not to do. A simple reformat did the trick.